# Marking DataContract Correctly for Deserialization using WCF

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-parsing

I have this object below I am trying to mark it correctly for deserialzation from xml. It is using WCF.

```
[DataContract(Name="Task")]
    public partial class Task
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string prop1
        { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public ChildrenProps ChildProp1{ get; set; }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public partial class ChildrenProps 
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ConfigurationSettings Prop1
        { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public ConfigurationSettings Prop2
        { get; set; }
    }


    [DataContract]
    public partial class ConfigurationSettings
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Value
        { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the XML.

```
<Task>
  <prop1>aaaaa</prop1>
  <ChildProp1>
    <Prop1>bbbbbb</Prop1>
    <Prop2>cccccc</Prop2>
  </ChildProp1>
</Task>
```

I am using this method for deserialization

```
public T Deserialization<T>()
{
    var reader = new StringReader(configuration);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    var instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    return instance;
}
```

It does not work
 for the Child elements and returns null in the object but does work for everything else. Any help in marking this correctly would be a great help.

Comment: There is an other Serializer for such kind of work. It is also WCF default Serializer. But right now I cannot look for that class name.

Comment: WCF uses DataContract serializer on data contracts by default, you need not do manual serialization and deserialization

Comment: Please, post `ChildrenProps` type definition.

Comment: Sorry Denis Just named it incorrectly it was always up there just under an incorrect name, check above.

Comment: @Vignesh Natraj sorry what do you mean? How do I get the XML into the object?

Answer (score 0):

Your Serialized XML is incorrect, according to the class information you have provided this is the serialized XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Task xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <prop1>HelloWorld</prop1>
  <ChildProp1>
    <Prop1>
      <Value>propr1</Value>
    </Prop1>
    <Prop2>
      <Value>propr2</Value>
    </Prop2>
  </ChildProp1>
</Task>
```

And this is how you serialize a object

```
Task taskObj = new Task();
taskObj.prop1 = "HelloWorld";
taskObj.ChildProp1 = new ChildrenProps();
taskObj.ChildProp1.Prop1 = new ConfigurationSettings(){ Value = "propr1"};
taskObj.ChildProp1.Prop2 = new ConfigurationSettings() { Value = "propr2" };

XmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, taskObj);
```

You can use this XML to deserialize and test your code.